# MySQL group by a certain type and select the latest row?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate

Imagine a table with columns type, date, message. And some rows looking like this (type | date | message):

```
1 | 1310572318 | Hello
1 | 1310572317 | Hi
2 | 1310572315 | Wassup
3 | 1310572312 | Yo
3 | 1310572311 | Hey
3 | 1310572309 | Eyo
1 | 1310572305 | Hello
1 | 1310572303 | Good Day
```

Is it possible to group them by type, and selecting the latest (ordered by date) so the result would be:

```
1 | 1310572318 | Hello
2 | 1310572315 | Wassup
3 | 1310572312 | Yo
1 | 1310572305 | Hello
```

I'm pretty sure I have to use some MySQL Aggregate functions, but I'm not very good at them, so I'm asking for a little bit of help here.

Comment: Either your result is wrong (you have type "1" both times) or your description was not correct.

Comment: Yes thats my intention ty write "1" multiple times. You see, the types can occur anywhere anytime.

Comment: He meant you have multiple `type=1` in the **results** (4th row). That is not consistent with your description (group by **type**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any [aggregate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html) that can use a different column so that you could get the message with the latest date.

This could be helpful:

```
SELECT 
    `type`, 
    MAX(`date`) AS `max_date`, 
    (SELECT `t2`.`message` FROM `table` AS `t2` WHERE `t2`.`type` = `t1`.`type` ORDER BY `t2`.`date` DESC LIMIT 1)
FROM `table` AS `t1`
GROUP BY `type`
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
Select type, date, message from tableName
group by type
having min(date)
```

Please note, that the last line is not valid

```
 1 | 1310572305 | Hello
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your dates are represented as integers like you have showing here, you can try the following:

```
SELECT type, MAX(date), message
FROM myDB.myTable
GROUP BY type;
```

Unless i'm missing something fundamental here, this should do the trick.