# MySQL query to pull only the latest record

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, greatest-n-per-group

I am creating a simple chat module where there are two levels.

1. Inbox
2. Conversation

in the Inbox i want to list the conversation between me and other users and display the latest chat message from that particular user.

messages(id, user_id, receiver_id, message, timestamp)

Dummy data

```
1, 1, 2, "hi there", today

2, 1, 4, "Hey Tommy", yesterday

3, 1, 2, "Wanna meet tonite?", now
```

Now when i display the list i want to just display two messages 
one with user id - 4 and user id 2. But the latest message of userid 2 should be displayed only.

How to do a query where i can get only the latest row from a particular user ?

Comment: Duplicate of many, many [greatest-n-per-group](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3182436/132382) questions.

Comment: No, this does not need a group by

Comment: sorry i wanted to achieve this in CAKEPHP forgot to mention it

Comment: @Ajreal then how can i do it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL group by a certain type and select the latest row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693796/mysql-group-by-a-certain-type-and-select-the-latest-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is beleive is an efficient way to acheive this:

```
SELECT M1.* FROM Messages M1 LEFT JOIN Messages M2 
ON M1.ReceiverID = M2.ReceiverID AND M1.Timestamp < M2.Timestamp
WHERE M2.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
FROM `messages`
WHERE `user_id` = 1
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC) TT
GROUP BY TT.`receiver_id`;
```

Hope the above helps!

Answer (score 1):

I would try it like this:

```
$user_id = 2;

$latestmessage = $this->Message->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'user_id' => $user_id
    ),
    'order' => 'id DESC'
));
```

Comment: i want the first message from very group :(

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
$latest_per_user_id = $this->Message->find('all', array(
    'fields'=>'DISTINCT user_id',
    'order' => 'timestamp DESC'
));
```

EDIT: If you just need info for one user you can do this:

```
$latest_msg_by_user = $this->Message->find('first', array(
        'conditions'=>array('user_id'=>$user_id),
        'order' => 'timestamp DESC'
    ));
```

You could put this in a loop to get it for each user.

Comment: oh ok :) i get it. guess i was trying to get it done in one single query :)

Comment: If the first code works as I hope it does, then that might be the way to accomplish that :)
If not, the second one (when put in a loop) is the fallback plan.

Comment: i want the latest message from every user i have interacted. so i guess i will need to do a looping.